# TYPO3 version 12 LDAP

Tags: ldap, typo3

we used the ig_ldap_sso_auth-Extension last years, but there is no version for TYPO3 12.
Do you know any alternatives?

We tried ldap-Extension but it doesnt seems to be very stable.

So, would be nice to have hints about this topic.

Thanx a lot,
Boris

Comment: I do not know any alternatives. If the extension is not very stable on v12, I suggest to support the extension author in making it compatible either by providing pull requests or by providing financial help.

Answer (score 0):

The version for TYPO3 12 isn't ready yet.

On [github](https://github.com/xperseguers/t3ext-ig_ldap_sso_auth) you can find a branch `feature/TYPO3v12` you probably can use. Give feedback to the author and provide your part to the finalization of that extension.

Comment: Thanks, yes i have seen the branch. I took a look inside, but LDAP isnt an easy thing. I have no really experience in it. So i will see. It is a matter of time too.